# trying to format a partition, troubled by invalid blocks

Tags: partitioning, filesystem, ssd, fat32

I'd be grateful for any suggestions on how to proceed with a self-made problem:
I had a perfectly fine SSD connected to my NUC desktop running Ubuntu, then I tried to make it readable by a Windows machine...
I thought that I'd overwritten the SSD with a FAT32 filesystem, I could see the device in Windows Explorer, without its label, but the apps running on the windows machine couldn't see it.
So I set to, trying again but encountered a message about invalid blocks which I'm trying to fix: sudo mkfs -n "exTension" /dev/sda1
mke2fs 1.46.5 (30-Dec-2021)
mkfs.ext2: invalid blocks '/dev/sda1' on device 'exTension'
Any pointers would be much appreciated. I've been guided thus far by https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2Z6ouBYfZr8&list=PLT98CRl2KxKHKd_tH3ssq0HPrThx2hESW&index=17

Comment: Invalid blocks is usually a hardware failure. The drive is most likely dead or at least dying. With Windows by the way it should have not being fat32 but NTFS. For Ubuntu a better choice then ext2 is ext4 you seem to be working from some very old ideas.